# Express Static nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There is a `style.css` in `public`, but I can't seem to make the express static option work.  I deleted `express` and have done `npm install express`, but still it isn't working.  I just get a 404 error.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

I have added an `app.get()` block to insure express is properly running, but I am still unable to request the static file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Works just fine for me.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

---

```
mkdir public
cd public
touch README
```

---

**README**

```
test
```

---

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/README
test
```

---

```
$ npm ls
connect@1.6.1
express@2.4.4
```

Comment: reinstalled node.js and now everything is dandy, thanks.  Maybe it was outdated or something? oh well working now.

Comment: Very good :). It could be outdated ;).. Node.js API changes, as well as express API...

Answer (score 32):

An important detail that I have overlooked on multiple occasions now is that "public" is not in the URL of the static content you are delivering.

Alfred example nails it but it is easy to miss.  The location of the README file is not localhost:8080/public/README, but simply localhost:8080/README

Comment: +1 Totally missed this point.  I just spent an hour trying to figure out why everything from `localhost:8080/public/` was giving me 404s.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static

Comment: if you want localhost:8080/public/ to work then you need to do: `app.use('/public', express.static('public'));`