# serving image using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver

I have a image pic.jpeg which I have to display on browser.Here is snippet of code I have written.

```
var mimeTypes = {
            '.js' : 'text/javascript',
            '.css' : 'text/css',
            '.gif' : 'image/gif',
            '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
            '.html': 'text/html'
        };

    contenttype = mimeTypes[path.extname(req.url)];    
    pathname = "." + req.url;

var stream = fs.createReadStream(pathname);
        stream.on('error', function(error) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
            return;
        });
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', contenttype);
            res.writeHead(200);
            stream.on('open', function () {
                // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
                util.pump(stream, res, function(error) {
                //Only called when the res is closed or an error occurs
                console.log("Error:");
                res.end();
                return;
                });
            });
```

The above code works most of the time and the images displays like it should, but at times the image is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be serving static files through node.js. You should consider using Nginx or similar web server for the same.

Alternatively, you can use `connect` module to serve static files

```
var server = connect()
  .use('/static', connect.static(__dirname + '/static'))
  .use(router)
  .listen(port);
```

Make a new directory named `static` and put all files in it, so you will be able to access them by `/static/images/testimage.jpg`

Comment: I'm curious to know why you say "ideally" one should use nginx or similar instead of node for static files.

Comment: Removed it, Just so people don't get too curious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing static file serving yourself, why not use a library like Express?  You can see that being used here: [Express Static nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069360/express-static-nodejs) or see the API here: http://expressjs.com/api.html (search for "static").  It'll be a lot less code, and reliable.

Comment: yes I could do that, but this is just for educational purpose. I want to know how things work.