# How can I make standalone, executable js files with Node js Express without defining the routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble with Node JS.

With the Apache/php model, I'm able to make a standalone **save.php** file (takes a post request, saves to a txt file) without fooling around with the Apache server.

```
<?php file_put_contents ( 'content.txt' , $_POST['myData']);?>
```

In Node, I have **server.js** started to serve up whatever files I have in /public :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(req,res, next){
    if(req.accepts('html')){
    res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname+'/public/404.html');
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

How can I make a **save.js** file, e.g. /public/test_project1/save.js, that can be executed on an HTML form submission?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("content.txt", ???post data???)
```

Is there any way to avoid explicitly defining the app.post()... in **server.js** every time I make a new js file in /public? I'm looking for an architecture that allows me to create one node server to host various separate project files in /public

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express Static nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069360/express-static-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a endpoint for your post request, then  parse form data, a option could be [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware , finally save the content.

Something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyparser.urlenconded({extended:true}); // middleware for parse form data
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.post("/endpoint",function(req,res){
 //myData is input name
 var content = req.body.myData;
 fs.writeFile("content.txt", content,function(err){
  res.end("done");
 })
})

app.use(function(req,res, next){
    if(req.accepts('html')){
    res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname+'/public/404.html');
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

Then  you make a POST request to /endpoint with myData as input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with - modifying **server.js** to handle any POST requests within that folder. Is this dangerous?

```
app.post('/:folder/:file',function(req, res){
    filepath=__dirname+'/public/'+req.params.folder+'/'+req.params.file;
    fs.stat(filepath, function(err, stat) {
        if(err == null) {
            console.log('File exists');
            var anyFile=require(filepath)(req.body);
            res.redirect(anyFile);
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            res.send('File does not exist.');
        } else {
            res.send('Error: '+ err.code);          
        }
    });
});
```